# Sharing HFS+ (USB-HDD) over NFS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, nfs, hfs+, raspbian

I've hooked up an external HDD to my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. It shows up under /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 (two partitions). I followed numerous tutorials, but none seem to have a fix for my problem. This is, I want to share my USB connected hard drive over NFS (I know theres SMB et al, but I'm stubborn) and be able to mount it on my Macbook. Also, I want to make backups from my Macbook to that same hard drive. This was possible before I hooked the USB HDD to my Pi, when it was hooked to my Airport Extreme. I've tried the following:

```
pi@raspbmc:/media$ rpcinfo -p | grep nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs

pi@raspbmc:/media$ cat /proc/filesystems | grep nfs
nodev   nfs
nodev   nfs4
nodev   nfsd

pi@raspbmc:/media$ rpcinfo -p | grep portmap
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper

pi@raspbmc:/media$ cat /etc/exports
/media/Data *(rw,sync,subtree_check)
/media/Backups *(rw,sync,subtree_check)

pi@raspbmc:/media$ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
[ ok ] Stopping NFS kernel daemon: mountd nfsd.
[ ok ] Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon....
[....] Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...exportfs: /media/Backups does not support NFS export
exportfs: /media/Data does not support NFS export
. ok
[ ok ] Starting NFS kernel daemon: nfsd mountd.

pi@raspbmc:/media$ sudo exportfs -ra
exportfs: /media/Backups does not support NFS export
exportfs: /media/Data does not support NFS export
```

according to the following link:

> https://www.debian-administration.org/users/lee/weblog/21

running the following commands should fix it (I've done this already so the output log is slightly different):

```
pi@raspbmc:/media$ sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sda2
** /dev/sda2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume SPARE appears to be OK.

pi@raspbmc:/media$ sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sda3
** /dev/sda3
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume SPARE appears to be OK
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to help me forward?